# How many is connection interval and connection event? (Bluetooth Low Energy)

Tags: bluetooth, btle

Now, I'm researching about BLuetooth Low Energy. Who can show the value of Connection Interval (min) and Connection Event (max) on Windows ? (just for BTLE).
Thanks so much!